# std::ostringstream vs std::string when converting integers to string

Tags: c++, stl

I always wondered and never found a satisfying explanation into why would

```
std::string str = 50;
cout << str
```

give you garbage or doesn't compile

and

```
std::ostringstream str << 50;
cout << str // or str.str()
```

works.

What is the inherit limitation that prevents std::string to implement a conversion operator from integers and integer like types?

Comment: How did you manage to get `std::string str = 50;` to compile?

Comment: There's no inherent limitation, conversion is just separated logically into other parts of the language (streams, `to_string`)

Comment: @AndyProwl (Maybe OP is using Visual Studio... :P)

Comment: @H2CO3@: Wait what? MS's stdlib has a `string` constructor that takes an `int`? I'm speechless :-/

Comment: Guys I am running GCC and yes string str = 50 does compile!!

Comment: Are you using `-fpermissive`? Don't. It enables waaaay too much compiler laziness. Also, enable all warnings.

Comment: BTW I know that string str = 50 isn't valid C++. ALL I am wondering is that why wouldn't the string constructor access ints? I really don't get why this question is getting downvoted

Comment: It fails on my gcc 4.8.1 with `error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'`

Comment: well I am running under windows mingw

Comment: But again that's not my point :). You are simply missing the word "garbage" in my post

Comment: @Kam, Containers have a numerical constructor for an initial size. `std::string` is like a container, so that can be confusing when some expect it to do that and some expect it to convert the argument. And if you know it's invalid C++, why are you trying to figure out how it behaves?

Comment: @chris: It does not have such a constructor for exactly this reason.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Tell the guys in the standard... (I imagine that he mistakenly used initialization instead of assignment in the question) `basic_string<>::operator=(TChar)` (which in my opinion is an error in the design of the component...) Sadly, 50 can be converted to `char`, which is the type of `TChar` in the case of `std::string`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: My low-quality crystal ball didn't let me see the OP's real code. If your assumption is correct, well done ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Got bit by that assignment in the past so I remember... (and it is consistent with `std::ostringstream str << 50;` ?!?!?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: lol, I didn't even get that far while reading the question. I think that makes good evidence. You have my +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that there is a mistake in writing the question, and that the first case is:

```
std::string str;
str = 50;
```

For some reason that escapes me, the standard does have an assignment operator that allows the assignment of a single `char` to a `std::string`, so that will create an empty string, and it will set it's value to contain a single character with numeric value 50.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str = 50;
```

This should not compile. `basic_string` has no constructor from a single `int`. Your implementation is defective. `basic_string` does not perform any conversions from any other types to string- it only handles strings.

```
std::ostringstream str << 50;
```

This performs a conversion from 50 to "50" and then outputs that. The `stringstream` *is* intended to convert from other types to text.

Comment: Yes I understand. That's why I am saying that std::string str = 50; is garbage but I would want an explanation on why is this not possible? why standard library implementation of string does not implement conversion operators

Comment: @Kam: Because `std::stringstream` exists to convert. `std::basic_string` performs one *and only one* job- holding an existing string.

Comment: Thank you! omg it seams you can't ask simple questions like that on SO without being downvoted

Comment: @Kam: I didn't downvote your question. It's a tad confusing but not terrible.

Answer (score -1):

there is several way to convert integer to string
but the way you mention is wrong.

look at the following, 
C++/STL:

```
ostringstream
to_string
```

C:

```
sprintf
```

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function. You also forgot `std::to_string`, the easiest one by far.

Comment: Yes, good lesson I always though that itoa and the other we're part of the C standard, I edited my answer and added sprintf to the list.